# Question related to functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f\colon X \mapsto Y$, $g\colon Y \mapsto Z$, if $f$ is an injection and $g$ is a surjection, what will be the composition   $g \circ f$   (surjection, injection or bijection) and how can I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried putting together some examples so you can see what's going on?

Comment: ditto, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why should it be that regular ? Take $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. It's neither injective nor surjective

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, $Y=\{0,1,2,3\}$, $Z=\{0,1,2\}$, and define $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=0$, $g(2)=1$, $g(3)=2$. We can check that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective. However the composition as a map from $X$ to $Z$ is not injective ($0$ and $1$ both map to $0$) and not surjective (no point in $X$ maps to $1\in Z$). It's not a bijection either.